# Using USGS data in 3ds max/ps/vue etc

Tags: united-states, usgs

I'd like to use USGS data in other software to produce 3d terrains. Ideally I would use IMG format as its most common from what I see. But how can I convert it to a 32 bit exr format for usage as displacement or height map etc etc?

Found few converters and other programs but none of them work.

Answer (score 1):

I used Scripts from USGS (http://gisdata.usgs.gov/website/USGS_Raster_Conversion_Scripts.zip) to convert the data using GDAL library from http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1800-x64-gdal-1-11-3-mapserver-6-4-2.zip

Can convert from IMG to GeoTiff that opens in PS.